# How to create Kafka consumer group using command line?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using community version of Confluent 5.2. I created a new topic with name `employee-info`.

I'm using flink as a consumer for above topic. In flink, for adding kafka source we need to pass in `group.id` (consumer group) as parameter. How do I create a new consumer group for my topic? I got few references which says use `kafka-consumer-group` with `--consumer-property group.id=group_name`. But, I cannot see the option when I run `kafka-consumer-group --help`

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to explicitly "prepare" the Kafka broker to add new consumer groups.

Just add the `group.id` in your Flink consumer, and the broker will automatically detect that this `group.id` is a new one or if it already exists.

The `kafka-consumer-group.sh` command line is mainly used to manage existing groups, in order to get the current offsets, or reset them, view the different members, ...